# Java RMI deployment

Tags: java, model-view-controller, tomcat, glassfish, 3-tier

I'm trying to develop a 3-tier architecture distributed java application.

1. Database Server
2. Application Server
3. Thin-Client Swing Applications

I haven't developed this type of applications before. I'm thinking to use java RMI to communicate between application server and thin-client applications. Also I'm gonna use Hibernate framework as ORM tool.

My question is, what are the components I need to deploy such an application.

1. Do I need some kind of servers like Tomcat or Glassfish?
2. How can I implement MVC model in such application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty large question, and there's no real one answer.  You really need to determine what are the needs of the app being built.

As far as RMI, you need a server process which provides an RMI host.  Glassfish provides one for you.  But, if yo're using glassfish, you'd probably want to use JPA / EJB3 as the persistence layer.  Which is simply Oracle's TopLink rebadged for the OpenSource world.

I'm not sure Tomcat comes with an RMI layer, although it's been a bit since I've developed for Tomcat in anger.  It's first and foremost a servlet engine.  If you were looking at a REST interface between client and server, that would be a good choice (although Glassfish provides a servlet engine as well).

If you really want to use Hibernate and you want RMI as the transport between client and server, don't discount Spring.  It will have RMI server engines where you define your Spring beans which call into Hibernate.  No Application Server required (apart from what Spring provides.

As far as MVC is concerned, from the client perspective you have Swing handling the View, with native Java implementing the Model and Controllers.  The Model, in this case, would be DTOs provided by the Services exposed by the RMI Server component.  I would think that Hibernate would be limited to the Server process, and there would be little View in the Services.  The Model in the Client code would be the DTO's and the surrounding framework which makes the RPCs to the services.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea, actually I'm developing an application which is much like an inventory management application in which the inventory will be accessed by many users with swing UI. And I've knowledge of hibernate and RMI but not of Spring and I've very limited time to complete the project. Is it worth learning Spring to develop this application than developing without Spring?

Comment: By all means, go with what you know, especially if there are time constraints.  You wouldn't need to learn all of Spring.  I would focus on their RmiServiceExporter (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html) which is just a simple way of binding your Java objects to an RMI service which is accessible publicly.  You can use as much or as little of the Spring Bean functionality as you like.  That said, it's pretty easy to pick up and once you start using it you probably won't look back.

Comment: More specifically, GlassFish Open Source Edition bundles EclipseLink, and Oracle GlassFish Server bundles TopLink. I 100% agree with not using Hibernate *UNLESS* there is a specific reason to do so. All quality tests that use JPA use EclipseLink to do so.  One route to take is to use a REST API, and pass JSON data with the help of Apache Jackson. JSON parsing is going to be in Java EE 7, and JSON binding will be coming later so you won't even need Jackson down the road.  Using REST is much more firewall friendly than RMI.

Comment: @EdH Thanks for introducing me to Spring. I'm now totally addicted to Spring. :-D

Comment: No worries.  It is impressive how little of Spring you need to know to get started.  You'll build it up as you go, but it is a wonderful tool to start using.  Have fun. :)